# Send Extra data on Audio Manager object to ensure android.media.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED Action Receiver receives this information

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I have a Broadcast Receiver that listens to Ringer mode change action as follows:

```
public class RingerModeStateChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("RECEIVER", "Ringer Change detected.");
    }
}
```

The manifest declaration is as follows:

```
<receiver android:name=".receivers.RingerModeStateChangeReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.media.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

My app changes the Ringer mode by making use of Audio Manager as shown below:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
if(someCondition) {
   audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
} else {
   audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
}
```

Is there a way to detect the ringer change to be coming from Audio Manager(may be by adding some extra content to the audio manager object) in my broadcast receiver?

**UPDATE:**

I have solved this problem by making use of **2 boolean variables**, one representing the updates made to RINGER by some external force and the other representing the updates made by my code. The former is true by default and the later false. The later becomes true only when the update to Ringer is about to be made by my code.

This allows the broadcast receiver to differentiate between external and internal changes made to the RINGER.

Although, this still is a workaround and I am still nowhere close to finding a solution internal to the android system (if at all one does exist).

Comment: The code is successfully receiving RINGER_MODE_CHANGED in onReceive, but you are trying to distinguish between when the ringer mode is changed inside your app versus when it is changed via an external source?

Comment: @Elletlar you have hit the nail on the head. This is my exact use case. My code will change the ringer status using Audio Manager based on some condition. It is also possible that the user would change the ringer status from device. I would then want to know where the change is from on my Receiver (RINGER_MODE_CHANGED action). Any help in this regard is deeply appreciated.

Comment: You can specify extra info in the IntentFilter when registering the receiver, but I am not aware of any way to coerce it into passing any of that data back. You could of course record the ringer mode and volume that you are expecting. As long as the settings are as the app requires, would it make any difference if the app or an external source changed it?

Comment: Yes it makes a difference. My app will change the ringer mode based off of multiple conditions. For example, based on the current location the ringer mode might change (and this check is running continually on some service). As a consequence, I would not really know what the ringer should be.

As far as IntentFilter is concerned, I did try to take this route but I never found an option to send extra data (is there a specific method?). Even if there is one, how will this help us differentiate internal to external updates?

Comment: @Elletlar To add onto my earlier statement, depending on who changed the ringer mode I would/wouldn't take a specific action. Therefore, understanding where the change is coming from is very important.

Comment: It sounds like what you want is something like a PendingIntent as you would have with the AlarmManager API. But as far as the RINGER_MODE_CHANGED broadcast, I do not know of any way to add info to it. I get what you're trying to do because I have an app that used to 'Override Silent'  by changing the mode and had to reset it correctly afterwards. Let's see if someone with more knowledge has an idea...

Comment: @Elletlar Appreciate you spending some time on this. Thank you.